# ITypeConverter<PizzaVm, Pizza>.Convert(PizzaVm, Pizza, ResolutionContext)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, automapper

```
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;
using ShopDx3.DomainModels;
using ShopDx3.DomainModels.Enums;
using ShopDx3.SharedKernel;
using ShopDx3.ViewModels;

namespace ShopDx3.Api.Factories
{
    public class OrderVmToOrderDmConverter : ITypeConverter<OrderVm, Order>
    {
        public Order Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var src = (OrderVm)context.SourceValue;
            var servType = Enumeration.FromDisplayName<ServiceType>(src.ServiceType.Replace(" ", ""));
            var pizzas = src.Pizzas.Select(x => Mapper.Map<PizzaVm, Pizza>(x)).ToList();
            var result = new Order(servType, pizzas, src.Name);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

When I build I get the error messae

> Error CS0535  'PizzaVmToPizzaDmConverter' does not implement interface member 'ITypeConverter.Convert(PizzaVm,
>   Pizza,
>   ResolutionContext)'   ShopDx3.Api D:\Projects\ShopDx3\src\ShopDx3.Api\Factories\PizzaVmToPizzaDmConverter.cs

Now I am trying

```
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;
using ShopDx3.DomainModels;
using ShopDx3.DomainModels.Enums;
using ShopDx3.SharedKernel;
using ShopDx3.ViewModels;

namespace ShopDx3.Api.Factories
{
    public class OrderVmToOrderDmConverter : ITypeConverter<OrderVm, Order>
    {
        public Order Convert(OrderVm pvm, Order p, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var src = (OrderVm)context.SourceValue;
            var servType = Enumeration.FromDisplayName<ServiceType>(src.ServiceType.Replace(" ", ""));
            var pizzas = src.Pizzas.Select(x => Mapper.Map<PizzaVm, Pizza>(x)).ToList();
            var result = new Order(servType, pizzas, src.Name);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

But with this code I get 
`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'ResolutionContext' does not contain a definition for 'SourceValue' and no extension method 'SourceValue' accepting a first argument of type 'ResolutionContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   ShopDx3.Api D:\Projects\ShopDx3\src\ShopDx3.Api\Factories\OrderVmToOrderDmConverter.cs  14  Active`

**UPDATED**

I downgrade my AutoMapper to version `3.3.1` it solved my problem,
Thank you all.

Comment: You don't seem to implement `TDestination Convert(TSource source, TDestination destination, ResolutionContext context)`

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: PizzaVmToPizzaDmConverter isn't in the code sample you've posted.
Is there some code you're not posting? I think there's some missing info

Comment: I posted it all, but there are code in  viewModels,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoMapper 5.0 removed the source value property from ResolutionContext in favor of passing in values directly. It turns out that putting the source values inside the ResolutionContext object is quite slow. Passing them in directly to your type converter is what allows AutoMapper 5.0 to be around 20-50x faster than AutoMapper 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

You method `Convert` has only one parameter. The error implies it requires 3 parameters.

So...

```
public Order Convert(ResolutionContext context)
{
   ...
}
```

should be:

```
public Order Convert(PizzaVm pvm, Pizza p, ResolutionContext context)
{
   ...
}
```

or... a second method should be added which has the desired signature.

Comment: Your second error is totally different from the first. It should be a second question on stackoverflow. Anyway... the error implies that your `context` (of type `ResolutionContext`) does not have a property named `SourceValue`. Look up the documentation of type `ResolutionContext` and see what properties it has. Or use another type which does have the property you are looking for.